# Get empy array after submit data

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to submit data through a form in ReactJs, but I'm getting an additional empty array along the inserted data.

This my function that handles submit through a button.

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState({
    first_name: '',
    last_name: ''
});

const onSubmit = (event) => {
    const person = {
        first_name: state.first_name,
        last_name: state.last_name
    }

    axios.post('localhost:3000/api/create.php', details)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            if (response.data) {
                setDetails([...details, person])
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setDetails({
        ...details,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
}
```

I handled all the input fields with one function handleChange().

I appreciate help!

Comment: It is hard to know without seeing how you handle the change event for your state (e.g: handleChange), we need more details about the rendering part (jsx)

Comment: @Ghazi I included the handleChange() function.

Answer (score 0):

in your axios call inside `then()` you are setting an array for the state:

```
setDetails([...details,person])
```

you should change it to:

```
setDetails(det=>({...details,person}))
```

btw inside the handleSubmit function,

```
 const person = {
        first_name: state.first_name,
        last_name: state.last_name
    }
```

`state` seems to be `undefined`, unless you have defined it somewhere else in your code.

I also suggest calling `event.preventDefault()` inside the `submitForm` to prevent hard loading whenever you submit the form.

Comment: I think this answer is correct. Using Typescript would have picked up these issues. I wanted to point out that `setDetails({...details,person})` should probably be `setDetails(prevDetails => ({...prevDetails,person}))` since the value of the state is being reused in `setState` call.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, i edited my code.

Comment: thank you for your response, but non of that worked it seems like a double axios request

Comment: double axios call is not really a possible thing, unless you do it intentionally, I suggest provide more of the code, show us how you rendered the component, and probably tell us more about `state`?